# Concept for a button that should be able to press longer then 30 sec

Tags: android, button, touch, long-press, motionevent

Is there an opportunity to implement an **element** that is able to get pressed **longer then 30 sec** until the MotionEvent Action_up timeout gets automatically fired?

Maybe an other concept of doing that job?

At the moment i have changed the image of an ImageButton by using the onTouchListener and the action_up and action_down define. But this concept is getting ruined by the auto `action_up` from android.

**Edit:**
The problem could be caused by samsungs android mod. It occurs on the Galaxy Tab2 7.0 Wifionly edition but not on the HTC Sensation XE. Does anyone got an Galaxy Tab2 to cross check this behavior?

Comment: I don't have this timeout on my device...isn't it somehow related to energy management configuration ?

Comment: there is an full wakelock established. might be wrong but i think that this should except the energymanagmet as the source of the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this issue on other samsung tablets. The result is that there is no problem at all. Just the Tablet i am using **Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 WiFi 7.0 (P3110)** got that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for your solution i suppose this will help you.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL) {
        // a long press of the call key.
        // do our work, returning true to consume it.  by
        // returning true, the framework knows an action has
        // been performed on the long press, so will set the
        // canceled flag for the following up event.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

The following Link will lead you to the correct result with other uses of Hard Keys.The link is as follows:-[Imp Link](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html)

Comment: But what is the keycode of my Imagebutton? i thought this keys were only hardkeys like the backbutton.

Comment: Ok if that way your not getting the solution, then this link will definitely work[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940357/imagebutton-onlongpress-causes-onclick-as-well)

Comment: Thats not the point. The Question is not about two clickevents its aber out an motion event and an ontouchlistener. if a button is pressed the action_down event happens then in android a timer got started that fires the action_up after a time allthogh the button is still pressed to prevent false input. The question is how to work around this.